# Are the Inverses of two asymptotically equivalent matrices themselves asymptotically equivalent

Tags: probability, asymptotics, consistency, matrix-inverse, delta-method

Suppose $M_n = P_n + op(1)$.

Is it the case that $M_n^{-1} = P_n^{-1} + op(1)$, if both $M_n^{-1}$ and $P_n^{-1}$ exist with probability going to 1 as $n$ increases? Can the Continuous Mapping Theorem can be used here?

Similarly, if  $M_n = P_n + Op(n^{-1/2})$, can we get $M_n^{-1} = P_n^{-1} + Op(n^{-1/2})$? Maybe from the Delta method?

Comment: Before examining the limiting case, you must wonder, "what properties does the inverse of the $o_p(1)$ matrix has? You have to start from $M_n^{-1} = (P_n+o_p(1))^{-1}$ and proceed from there.